# How to have a a single series data label on a grouped bar chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, label, bar-chart

I have an SSRS bar chart the shows some data in a handful of category groups. It's pretty straightforward and looks like this:

[image]

I've now got the need to segment each category into two series groups like so:
[image]

So far so good however I need to display the ungrouped percentage data labels (i.e. the requirement is to continue to show the percentage of each combined category group, NOT the percentage of the series group). So I need the bar chart from the second image but the data labels from the first.

For the life of me I cannot get the bar chart to show anything but the series group data labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this some time ago. I eventually achieved it by...

1. Creating a second dataset that fetched the values I wanted for the Data Labels
2. Selecting the Series in the Chart and in the Properties pane going to Labels, then setting `UseValueAsLabel = False`
3. Setting the "Label" property to be a LookUp() that fetched the appropriate value from my second dataset
4. Using the "Visible" property to hide the labels for one series so that they no longer show.

The end result was:

[image]

Hope that makes sense!

EDIT: Clarifying this slightly: step 4 is necessary because, as you're finding, the program will apply a label to each series. The other dataset fetches the combined total, so you want to hide the labels for all but one series to avoid having the same number repeated for each of the series.