# SSRS report - add extra table and chart to show occurence of character string in one of the main report's columns

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have an SSRS report based on stored procedure dataset. The report shows employees and their performance rating and uses bunch of parameters to filter the data.

Now I would like to add a table below that would dynamicaly count and show occurence of given mark in the main report. The table data should update according to what is visible in the main report after filtering it.

I wanted also to add a chart that would visualize this.

It would be feasible to do if the extra table and chart could run from the same dataset as the main report. This however seems impossible as this dataset does not always contain all the possible marks. It can happen that some marks are missing (when filtered or missing at all), and I would like to show the mark with zero value (and zero value bar in the chart) instead of just skipping it.

So far I was able to produce the table by hardcoding the headers and using SUM(IIF...) expressions under each header

Here is the expression for the "C" column.

=Sum(IIf(Fields!current_performance_rating.Value = "C", 1, 0))

It shows correctly the number of "C" marks appearing in the main report.

Now I am stuck with creating a chart that would show this.
I am not able to hardcode expressions similar to the ones in the table
and can't make the chart run from the main dataset, because the categories
would be missing after filtering the report (and not showing zero).

I tried linking datasets with Lookup function, but that did not work.

Which way should I go now? What is the best practice in such case?

### Thank you for any hints!

Thanks trubs.

I have right joined a view that contains
all the marks and that solves the issue
of missing categories.

The join is on something like 
tb.current_performance_rating = vw.performance_rating_code

I can now add the value series that counts
the occurence of current_performance_rating
per category. This works all fine.

However there is another table joined 
(on employee_id) that stores last year's rating.
This rating obviously may differ to the current one.

On the same chart I would like to add another 
series that counts last year's rating per category.
The category is there already, joined to the current
rating.

So you can have row like:
curren rating | last year's rating | category 
     C        |          H         |    C

So I am stuck, because when SSRS groups per category
it counts last year's H rating and displays
i the C category, while it should display it in H.

Sorry I can't post any pictures, seems like I
need more reputation points.
Hope you can understand what I mean.

Regards!

Comment: I think you now have 2 questions here?    if someone else answers the second question, its going top be difficult to mark a single answer as correct.  Also if people are going to *find* this post useful in the future, its best to stick to one question then ask another (as a separate question).

Comment: also, for your second question, post the query (or excerpt), results and expected output of the table.  Will be far easier to understand the problem

Comment: Yop, this is actually second question linked to the first one. Because I was not able to produce proper dataset for the table and chart I was trying to trick it by producing the table with expressions and chart basing on top of it. 

Thanks to your "You're likely better off changing your query to return results for marks where there are no values" hint and the LEFT JOIN advice I produced proper dataset for extra table and the chart. That was a way to go, thanks for the hints, I wil post my solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely better off changing your query to return results for marks where there are no values.

So instead of *inner* joining to your Performance Rating table, use a `Right Join` or `Full Outer Join`, so that all the data is always available.

eg:  Instead of...

```
SELECT p.PersonId, PersonName, g.Grade
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN PersonGrades pg  ON p.PersonId = pg.PersonId
INNER JOIN Grades g ON pg.GradeId = pg.GradeId
```

Use

```
SELECT p.PersonId, PersonName, g.Grade
FROM Grades g   
LEFT JOIN PersonGrades pg ON pg.GradeId = g.GradeId
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.PersonId = pg.PersonId
```

If that's not clear, post your query and we could help get the data in the right format.

Comment: Hi trubs!

I edited my question to add follow up to your answer. Please take a look.

Comment: This problem is very similar, I just need kind of combine two charts into one, showing bars under correct category.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698188/how-to-have-a-a-single-series-data-label-on-a-grouped-bar-chart

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I took it and produced proper, separate dataset for the extra table and chart. Please see my answer on what I exactly did. 
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The way to go was to simplify the dataset that the main report was based on.

Then I took the query from that dataset, used COUNT and GROUB BY to count number of occurence of each current year mark in the main report. Then I right joined (thx trubs!) with the view that contains all the possible marks (so that my extra table headers/chart categories would not disappear if they do not exist). As a result I got the number of occurence in current year per mark (table A).

Then I did almost exactly the same for the last year's rating, just used last year's mark. I got the number of occurence of last year's mark per mark (table B).

I inner joined table A and B on common column (the mark, which will always appear thanks to the RIGHT joins). This gave me a table (dataset eventualy) where I had:

mark | current year mark count | last year mark count.

Making a table and chart basing on this was really easy then.

There was some more fun of adding all the parameters from the main report to both the count queries, so that the counts would change when report is filtered. I also needed to make sure that count works not only when my filter criteria (in WHERE stetement) equal the parameter provided from the report, but also when they are NULLs (so I added OR column_i_filter_on IS NULL).

This works smoothly - the table content and chart changes when filtering changes (although runs slowly, as parameters are passed to two big dataset, one of which uses them twice).

Thanks for all the help!!

psh